# Modified Loss Function(s) for decorrelating neurons within a layer?

Tags: neural-networks, covariance, loss-functions, stochastic-gradient-descent

I'm looking for previous references on a specific topic. Does anyone know of any modified loss functions that incentivize a network to produce a diagonal neuron-to-neuron covariance matrix (averaging over training samples), ideally in a streaming setting i.e. the loss can be computed for a single training sample?

Something like https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06068, but where we don't need to explicitly compute the covariance matrix over the batch.